# How can I paste a string to textarea in browser with python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to send a string to the web page whose text field name is "inputfield". Actually, I can send the word to the page, but when I run the program, a new "chrome" page opens, which is used for testing purposes. However, I want to send a string to the field on a chrome page that is already open.

Here my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/turkish"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r"C://Program Files//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"
chrome_driver_binary = 'chromedriver.exe'
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, options=options)
driver.get(url)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

text_area = driver.find_element_by_id('inputfield')
text_area.send_keys("Hello")
```

Nothing happens when I run this code. Can you please help? Can you run it by putting a sample web page in the url part?

Thank you.

EDIT: It is working when I deleted options. But still opening a new page when I run it. Is there a way use a page which already open on background.

```
chrome_driver_binary = 'chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary)
driver.get('https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/turkish')

text_area = driver.find_element_by_id('inputfield')
text_area.send_keys("Hello")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the popup prior to sending keys.

```
driver.get('https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/turkish')
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowallSelectionWrapper"))).click()
text_area = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "inputfield")))
text_area.send_keys("Hello")
```

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem with similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your question but if the issue is multiple tabs or windows being opened then:

you can switch between the windows as:

```
// you can move to specific handle    
chwd = driver.window_handles
print(chwd)
driver.switch_to.window(chwd[-1])
```

you should shoul switch to the correct window before you can interact with elements on that window

just switch to the window that was already opened bypassing the index

**If the problem is that you want to interact with an already opened chrome then you should follow below steps:**

Start chrome with debug port:

`<path>\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=1559`

Python :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1559")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: It is not my problem but I can use this method for another project. Thanks for your help.